# como puedo si un condicion no se cumple redireccionar

Tags: twig

Es posible realizar una redireccion con el motor de plantillas de `twig` necesito hacer una validación mediante una variable que tengo, si la variable no se cumple redireccionar a `/account/login`

```
{% account.islogin==false%}

{#redireccion /account/login/
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

La redireccion se hace antes de entrar en el template, tenes que usar la funcion de php header, para modificar el header "Location" del response http
`header("Location: $url_a_redireccionar");`